# Read and write autoincrement values from trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am having trouble with mysql triggers assigning primary key values. Consider my tables:

**v_object** : v_object_id,create_date, .. some generic attributes
 **users**    : user_id,name, .. attributes of a user

I have a trigger on users table as follows:

```
create trigger new_vobject_for_user before insert on users
for each row begin
    insert into v_object(v_type,...) values(...);
    set NEW.id = // How do i get the new v_object's id here?
end;
```

When I insert an user, I need the vobject created and use its new auto incremented value for user_id.

I also would like to know if there is a way to insert the users without specifying the id. For example:

```
insert into users(n1,n2,n3,...) values(m1,m2,m3,...);
```

It gives me an error saying user_id is not specified. And that's true.. what I am trying to do is create vobject & generate id in the trigger.

Comment: If you can't omit `user_id` in the INSERT statement, then it isn't an autoincrement column.

Comment: user_id is not auto increment.. its just pk of users table. vobject's id is auto increment

Comment: Then I don't understand that bit of the question. What do you want MySQL to do with `users.user_id` when you don't set a explicit value?

Comment: What about the insert statement? how can I avoid the user_id in insert statement?

Comment: Please sit down for a minute and think about it: you have a primary key, you don't want to assign a value manually and you don't want MySQL to set it for you. So, what do you want then? A `NULL` primary key??

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario what I am trying to do is avoid passing a static value in the insert statement.. like `insert into users values(0,'xyz',140,..)` .. the 0 is just a dummy value but a correct value is generated by the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

```
create trigger new_vobject_for_user before insert on users
for each row begin
    insert into v_object(v_type,...) values(...);
    set NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
end;
```

alternatively have a look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables and get last auto increment for table `v_object`

```
create trigger new_vobject_for_user before insert on users
for each row begin
    insert into v_object(v_type,...) values(...);
    set NEW.id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'v_object')
end;
```

Comment: Could you explain what side effects we can expect?

Comment: OK, it was my fault. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html says, that you could have only one trigger of same type and execution time. Oracle allows multiple triggers, but not MySQL, thanks

Comment: What about the insert statement? how can I avoid the user_id in insert statement?

Comment: Ermmm, why not always defining `user_id` in your statement with static value (i.e. `0`)? The trigger then sets a new value. You've defined `user_id` as PK, PK's always have to be not null, so you have to set it in your `INSERT`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT @Result:=LAST_INSERT_ID();` to get the last insert id.

or

```
SET Result=LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT Result;
```

Comment: `SELECT` in trigger would fail, use only `SET`